# Is it possible to apply the distributive property only once

Tags: python, sympy

I've been using sympy to help simplify expressions, but at times I would like sympy to only do a limited amount of simplification/expansion.

For example, suppose I have the code:

```
x = symbols("x")

poly = x*(x**2+x*(x+2))
```

If I do, `expand(poly)`, I expand to an expression with no parenthesis, but is it possible to apply only the outer distributive property?, i.e., to get just: `x^3+x^2(x+2)`?

I tried looking at https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/manipulation.html, but it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `deep=False`:

```
In [51]: x = symbols("x")
    ...: 
    ...: poly = x*(x**2+x*(x+2))

In [52]: poly
Out[52]: 
  ⎛ 2            ⎞
x⋅⎝x  + x⋅(x + 2)⎠

In [53]: expand_mul(poly, deep=False)
Out[53]: 
 3    2        
x  + x ⋅(x + 2)
```

This example also works with `expand` but since you are being selective about the manipulation that you want I suggest using `expand_mul`.

Comment: That works perfectly for what I wanted, thank you!